# Compatible Motherboard and CPU for 24GB Ram

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I'm fairly new to computer hardware and would like some help. I've got [Kingston 24GB RAM](http://www.kingston.com/press/2010/memory/01a.asp) and looking for a compatible Motherboard and CPU.

Comment: way too vague. What type of RAM for a start ? Also, do you really need 24GB ? And why try to fit a motherboard and cpu to your RAM ? Normally you work the other way around.

Comment: @Sirex - i've already got the RAM and looking for something that will work with it.

Answer (score 4):

1. There is no way you will be using 24 GB of RAM, especially if you are relatively new to computing. This amount of RAM is generally reserved for high-end servers, scientific research or large-scale Virtualization systems.
2. The 24GB kit is composed of six 4GB modules, so you need a motherboard with six DDR3 memory slots. The kit is design to work with i7 chips, so that's the CPU you'll be looking for.
3. http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=40000280&IsNodeId=1&Description=x58%20motherboards&name=Intel%20Motherboards Listing of motherboards that should work for you.

Comment: Without knowing what n002213f will be using the computer for it is impossible to objectively rationalize #1. While n002213f may be new to computer hardware they may not be new to computer software (with respect to their field).

Comment: Yes, you are right about that. #1 isn't meant negatively, it's merely a pointer to make sure he isn't dishing out thousands of extra dollars that he doesn't need to spend. This is why I replied with a listing of motheboard options he has.

Comment: the kit is composed of 8GB X 3 chips. From the brochure, it works with i7, what i wanted was a specific CPU and Motherboard that is know to work with the RAM. I believe not all i7 CPU and Motherboards are equal.

Comment: @Xantec - thanks, i will be virtualizing servers (MySQL, Glassfish) for our startup.

Comment: Will `Intel® X58 Chipset` motherboard and `LGA1366 Intel® Core™ i7` suffice.

Comment: @n002213f - I'd argue anything less would be a waste.  (Note that it's redundant to list both of those - they're compatible with each other and nothing else.  X58 implies 1366.)

Comment: @Shinrai - now i know.

Answer (score 0):

The memory address calculation facility in the processor may no have the capability to address 24GB of RAM and you could check this out, maximum may be 8GB and that would depend on the number of RAM slots and connectors available in the board and what is legal in the locality of use.